# create column one df if exists in other df R

Tags: r

I have a df:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  sample_id = c('SB024', 'SB026', 'SB027', 'SB026', 'SB027'), 
  VAR = c('10g.76789732G>A','10g.76789732G>A','10g.76789732G>A','11g.102195430G>A','11g.102195430G>A'), 
  REF = c('G','G','G','C','C'),
  ALT = c('A','A','A','T','T'))

df1
  sample_id              VAR REF ALT
1     SB024  10g.76789732G>A   G   A
2     SB026  10g.76789732G>A   G   A
3     SB027  10g.76789732G>A   G   A
4     SB026 11g.102195430G>A   C   T
5     SB027 11g.102195430G>A   C   T
```

I have made a second dataframe with the unique entries of VAR column:

```
library(dplyr)
VAR_to_check<-as.data.frame(unique(df$VAR))
names(VAR_to_check)<-"VAR"
ref<-unique(left_join(VAR_to_check,df1[,c(2:4)],by="VAR"))

ref
               VAR REF ALT
1  10g.76789732G>A   G   A
4 11g.102195430G>A   C   T
```

I would now like to add columns to the 'ref' dataframe for each sample_id like so:

```
               VAR REF ALT SB024 SB026 SB027
1  10g.76789732G>A   G   A    NA    NA    NA
4 11g.102195430G>A   C   T    NA    NA    NA
```

Then for each VAR in 'ref', if the sample_id has an entry in 'df1' then fill with ALT and if not fill with REF. So for this data it would be:

```
               VAR REF ALT SB024 SB026 SB027
1  10g.76789732G>A   G   A     A     A     A
4 11g.102195430G>A   C   T     C     T     T
```

I'm very stuck on this and have previously posted a question [Ifelse to Compare the content of columns with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69293645/ifelse-to-compare-the-content-of-columns-with-dplyr/69295011#69295011) but this wasn't quite right as I need to get the unique VAR entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option -

```
library(dplyr)

result <- df1 %>% distinct(VAR, REF, ALT)

values <- unique(df1$sample_id)

result[values] <- do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y, z) 
                         ifelse(values %in% df1$sample_id[df1$VAR == z], x, y), 
                         result$ALT, result$REF, result$VAR))
result

#               VAR REF ALT SB024 SB026 SB027
#1  10g.76789732G>A   G   A     A     A     A
#2 11g.102195430G>A   C   T     C     T     T
```

Inside `Map` for each `VAR` we return `ALT` if the `values` is present in `sample_id` or else return `REF` value. This will return us a list of vectors which are combined together as a dataframe with `do.call(rbind, ..)`.

Comment: Wow. Super cool. I like the distinct function. Would you mind just walking me through the do.call part? I want to learn from good coders like yourself.

Comment: I added some explanation in the answer. `Map` is like a `for` loop but instead of iterating over one value we can iterate over multiple values. Here we loop over 3 variables i.e `ALT` (`x`), `REF`(`y`) and `VAR` (`z`).